# Is this code thread safe for unique id in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a simple code where I want to have objects generated with unique id. Here is the code snippet

```java
public class Test {

    private static long counter = 0;
    private long id;

    private Test() {
        // Don't worry about overflow
        id = counter++;
    }

    // Will this method always Test Object with unique id?
    public static Test getTest() {
        return new Test();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

Would like to know if getTest method is called by multiple threads will all TestObjects have unique id's?

Comment: you need to mark method as synchronized, think of a scenario, multiple threads access method same time.

Comment: No... this is definitely not thread safe. You have a mutable state - "counter".

Comment: Also... generating guaranteed UUID's in parallel-distributed environment is not a trivial problem. It can be a serious research problem. But you can generate UUID's with very very high probability

Comment: It is not thread safe because `counter++` is not an atomic operation. For this reason the answers below correctly suggest to use an `AtomicLong`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not thread-safe because two threads can execute counter++ at same time and you can get unexpected results.

You should use AtomicInteger:

```
public class Test {

    private static AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);
    private long id;

    private Test() {
        // Don't worry about overflow
        id = counter.incrementAndGet();
    }

    // Will this method always Test Object with unique id?
    public static Test getTest() {
        return new Test();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: `id` should probably be `final` or `volatile`. Else some thread might see an id of 0 instead of the real id.

Comment: @xehpuk `final` yes, `volatile` no.  Both keywords will have the desired effect at run time, but code is not just meant to be runnable:  It's also meant to be readable.  `volatile` tells the reader, that this value is going to change.  But, it doesn't ever change.  `final` is much more appropriate.

Comment: @jameslarge True. My comment was just refering to thread-safety. `final` makes much more sense, more so when not dealing with concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not thread-safe for generating unique IDs. It may well happen that objects will receive non-unique IDs. You could use AtomicInteger/AtomicLong to make this work (i.e., `private static AtomicLong counter = (new AtomicLong())`) and then `counter.getAndIncrement()` in the constructor of `Test`.

The reason it is not thread-safe is that each processor/core has its own set of registers and without synchronization the variable may have inconsistent copies in the different processors/cores. Even on a single-processor system, preemptive multi-threading introduces the same problem. Synchronization would not be needed in non-preemptive threading systems.

Comment: Or an AtomicLong in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use synchronize block in your constructor if you want to lock class-level variable (Not the instance variable because for instance variable there is no need of synchronization . only one thread will be able to create object at a time).
so you can try this also as your constructor.

```
private Test() {
    // Don't worry about overflow
    synchronized(Test.class){
    id = counter++;
    }
}
```